# Unexpected behavior of WeakHashMap with Map as key returning null value after modification of key

Tags: java, hashmap, hashcode

We need to cache some information about some objects therefore we are using `java.util.WeakHashMap`. If we the key is `java.util.HashMap` we are seeing unexpected behavior.

Example:

```
WeakHashMap<Object, Object> whm = new WeakHashMap<>();
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
whm.put(map, "map");
System.out.println(map + ": " + whm.get(map) + " " + whm + " " + whm.containsKey(map));

map.put("key", "value");
System.out.println(map + ": " + whm.get(map) + " " + whm + " " + whm.containsKey(map));
System.out.println(map.hashCode());
System.out.println(whm.entrySet().stream().map(e -> e.getKey().hashCode()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
System.out.println(whm.entrySet().stream().map(e -> e.getKey() == map).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

output is:

```
{}: map {{}=map} true
{key=value}: null {{key=value}=map} false
112004910
[112004910]
[true]
```

Why is `whm.get(map)` `null` after calling `whm.put(map, "map")`?

Same result for `java.util.HashSet`...

For `AtomicInteger` it works as expected:

```
WeakHashMap<Object, Object> whm = new WeakHashMap<>();
AtomicInteger integer = new AtomicInteger(0);
whm.put(integer, "integer");
System.out.println(integer + ": " + whm.get(integer) + " " + whm + " " + whm.containsKey(integer));

integer.set(1);
System.out.println(integer + ": " + whm.get(integer) + " " + whm + " " + whm.containsKey(integer));
```

results in:

```
0: integer {0=integer} true
1: integer {1=integer} true
```

Answer (score 8):

This has nothing to do with it being a *weak* map, and everything to do with you modifying a map key, which is basically something you should avoid doing. By adding an entry to the map, you're changing its hash code. This is easily demonstrated:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        System.out.println(map.hashCode());
        map.put("key", "value");
        System.out.println(map.hashCode());        
    }
}
```

At that point trying to fetch the entry will fail, because its hash code no longer matches the hash code it was inserted with.

`AtomicInteger` doesn't override either `equals` or `hashCode`, so you get object identity equality instead - its hash code doesn't change when you call `set`.

Comment: @André: Or you need to not use mutable keys. (It's fairly odd to use a map as a key in another map.)

Answer (score -1):

My solution was to add WeakMap using equality wich works as desired in this case:

```
import java.util.IdentityHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.WeakHashMap;

/**
 * {@link WeakHashMap} also using equality to support mutable keys with changing {@link Object#hashCode()} like {@link IdentityHashMap}. In case of equality
 * checking the performance will be {@code O(n)}. <b>Currently just {@link Map#get(Object)} and {@link Map#containsKey(Object)} are supported for equality.</b>
 *
 * @author Andre Schulz
 */
public class WeakIdentityMap<K, V> extends WeakHashMap<K, V> {

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        boolean result = super.containsKey(key);

        if (result) {
            return result;
        }

        for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : super.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getKey() == key) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public V get(Object key) {
        V value = super.get(key);

        if (value != null) {
            return value;
        }

        for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : super.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getKey() == key) {
                return entry.getValue();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not really a HashMap anymore and should probably not extend `WeakHashMap`.

Comment: It is a kind of rather inefficient "WeakIdentityMap" as you are not using the hashcodes, and the cautions noted in the [JavaDocs of IdentityHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) about intentionally breaking the Map contract apply here as well.